# Canonical way of getting differences from server

Tags: jquery, python, json, browser

I would like to update a web page as changes are made to the server. I'm using a websocket to transfer data between the two.

Say I'm sending data in the form of JSON that is formed into a table.

```
{
  "My Tasks" : [
    {
      "Column 1" : "Task A1",
      "Column 2" : "Task A2",
      "Column 3" : "Task A3"
    },
    {
      "Column 1" : "Task B1",
      "Column 2" : "Task B2",
      "Column 3" : "Task B3"
    },
    {
      "Column 1" : "Task C1",
      "Column 2" : "Task C2",
      "Column 3" : "Task C3"
    }
  ]
}
```

This JSON is stored/cached on the server and sent to the browser which loads it into a nice table. Whenever updates are made to the server, I want the value to (potentially) change, but I'd like to refrain from basically re-setting the entire table.

I've looked into a number of utilities like [JSON-Delta](http://json-delta.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to attempt to store each of the diffs in a "commit"-like fashion. Essentially, when an change is detected, JQuery would submit the current "commit" or "state" and the server would calculate the differences from the browser's current state to the server's current state based on sequentially stored diffs. However, this is tedious and I've not found an efficient way to implement it in on either side.

The server is a Flask-like application running a RESTful API.

I'm just wondering the canonical way of updating the browser without transferring the entirety of the data.

Comment: what i comprehend that you want to change only the certain differences made in the table in the server(by you or someone else) , and those changes should be visible on the browser, only to the changed entity.

So, why not transverse `json`? like as the change is made, use the api to post the `json` data of the changes made, like if in first node `"Column 3"` id changed then the `json` will be `{"Column 3": "stuff"}`